# Reset PostgreSQL Administrator Password in Debian

Tags: linux, postgresql, passwords, debian

I forgotten/mistype password during PostgreSQL installation.

I tried to use resources online but the file pathway is always not found.

Any specific step by step for Debian?

Answer (score 0):

psql -U postgres
postgres=# alter user postgres with password 'NEW_PASSWORD';
postgresl=# \q

Change the authentication method in the configuration file at /opt/bitnami/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf from md5 to trust and reload the configuration.

sudo sed -ibak 's/^([^#]*)md5/\1trust/g' /opt/bitnami/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
sudo -u postgres pg_ctl reload
Connect to the PostgreSQL database and set the password to a new value:

psql -U postgres
postgres=# alter user postgres with password 'NEW_PASSWORD';
postgresl=# \q
Finally, change the authentication method back to md5 and reload the old PostgreSQL configuration:

sudo sed -i 's/^([^#]*)trust/\1md5/g' /opt/bitnami/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
sudo -u postgres pg_ctl reload

Comment: I faced error after the first line 

"psql: warning: extra command-line argument "alter" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "user" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "postgres" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "with" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "password" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "NEW_PASSWORD" ignored
psql: error: could not connect to server: invalid connection option "postgres"
bash: q: command not found"